# Issue with AES Encryption and Decryption between Node.js and React Native using Crypto and CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, encryption

I am facing an issue with AES encryption-decryption between a Node.js server and a React Native client. On the server side, I'm using the built-in crypto module of Node.js to encrypt the data, and on the client side, I'm using the react-native-crypto-js package to decrypt the data.

Server side encryption function (Node.js):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function encrypt(text) {
  const password = "TEST123";
  const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, 'salt', 32);
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');

  return { gameId: iv.toString('hex'), gameData: encrypted };
}
```

Client side decryption function (React Native):

```
import CryptoJS from 'react-native-crypto-js';

function decryptGameData(encryptedText, ivHex) {
  const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("TEST123");
  const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ivHex);
  const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedText, key, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC });

  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

The problem is that I'm always getting a "Malformed UTF-8 data" error on the client side when I call decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8).

I've confirmed that the IVs match on both ends, and the password used to create the key is the same.

I've already tried different key lengths, different AES modes (aes-128-cbc, aes-256-cbc), but the problem still persists. I've even tried to use toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex) instead of toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8), but no success.

What could be causing this "Malformed UTF-8 data" error on the client side when trying to decrypt the data? Is there something wrong with my encryption-decryption methods?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would probably be easier and safer to just use HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

The NodeJS/crypto code uses *scrypt* as key derivation, the React-Native/CryptoJS code does not. Therefore, different keys are applied and decryption fails.

As solution, a `scrypt` library must be used on the React-Native/CryptoJS side. For instance, the following code uses [scrypt-js](https://github.com/ricmoo/scrypt-js). For convenience, [react-native-buffer](https://github.com/craftzdog/react-native-buffer) is also applied. I.e. the *dependencies* section of *package.json* additionally contains the following entries:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react-native-crypto-js": "1.0.0",
    "scrypt-js": "3.0.1",
    "@craftzdog/react-native-buffer": "6.0.5"
    ...
```

The code below:

```js
import scrypt from 'scrypt-js';
import CryptoJS from 'react-native-crypto-js';
const Buffer = require("@craftzdog/react-native-buffer").Buffer;
...

function decryptGameData(encryptedText, ivHex) {
    var N = 16384, r = 8, p = 1, dkLen = 32;
    var pwd = Buffer.from('TEST123', 'utf-8')
    var salt = Buffer.from('salt', 'utf-8')
    var key = scrypt.syncScrypt(pwd, salt, N, r, p, dkLen)
    var keyWA = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(Buffer.from(key).toString('latin1'))
    var ivWA = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ivHex)
    var encryptedTextCP = {ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedText)}
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedTextCP, keyWA, { iv: ivWA, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC });
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}

var ciphertextFromNodeJS = {
  gameId: 'eddc7afa0db2a72f06f7ddc33232edfd',
  gameData: 'dacda519941904152fef144e69368a3faf058f4ae8f34c4709c0b3380a183007fe41a383cf01f2b85a0177359139cf54'
}
var encryptedText = ciphertextFromNodeJS.gameData
var ivHex = ciphertextFromNodeJS.gameId
console.log(decryptGameData(encryptedText, ivHex)) // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

then decrypts the ciphertext created with the NodeJS/crypto code.